Django 5 views function dont accepts POST what wroted with javascript
My problem: DoesNotExist at /cart/cart_add/
product = Products.objects.get(id=product_id)
becose product_id = None
When I try get  product_id in request.POST
it`s value = None
I learn django but don`t now JS.
Perhaps:
Mistake in JS file
This code work with django4 (I use django5)
jquery-ajax.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var successMessage = $("#jq-notification");
    $(document).on("click", ".add-to-cart", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var goodsInCartCount = $("#goods-in-cart-count");
        var cartCount = parseInt(goodsInCartCount.text() || 0);
        var product_id = $(this).data("product-id");
        var add_to_cart_url = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: add_to_cart_url,
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                successMessage.html(data.message);
                successMessage.fadeIn(400);              
                setTimeout(function () {
                    successMessage.fadeOut(400);
                }, 7000);
                cartCount++;
                goodsInCartCount.text(cartCount);
                var cartItemsContainer = $("#cart-items-container");
                cartItemsContainer.html(data.cart_items_html);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("text");
            },
        });
    });

catalog.html
   
<a href="{% url "cart:cart_add" %}" class="btn add-to-cart" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}">  
{% csrf_token %}
<img class="mx-1" src="{% static "deps/icons/cart-plus.svg" %}" alt="Catalog Icon" width="32" height="32">

views.py
def cart_add(request): 
    
    product_id = request.POST.get("product_id") 
    product = Products.objects.get(id=product_id)
    user_cart = get_user_carts(request)
    cart_items_html = render_to_string(
        "carts/includes/included_cart.html", {'carts': user_cart}, request=request
    )    
    response_data =  {
        'masage': 'Тext', 
        'cart_items_html': cart_items_html, 
    }
    return JsonResponse(response_data) 

